# É possível configurara o upload_max_filesize via .htaccess

Tags: php

É possível configurara o upload_max_filesize do php pelo arquivo .htaccess?
Já que eu não tenho acesso ao arquivo php.ini do servidor.

Comment: +1 ótima pergunta. Eu ia responder que não tinha jeito, mas uma breve pesquisada (em inglês) acabei descobrindo que tem um jeito.

Comment: Que tal um pequena pesquisa no google? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992376/how-to-set-upload-max-filesize-in-htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992376/how-to-set-upload-max-filesize-in-htaccess)

Comment: @Skramewell Somos uma comunidade não só pra responder coisas que não tem resposta, mas trazer conteúdo, esse tipo de comentário soa mal, outra coisa nem todos estão familiarizados com o inglês, a ideia da comunidade é também trazer bom conteúdo em português daqui até o outro lado do atlântico. Por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva e seja bem vindo a comunidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra complementar a outra resposta, para usar configurar o php pelo .htaccess é necessário ter instalado no servidor o `mod_php`, se o seu servidor ou hospedagem não tiver disponibilidade vai aparecer uma mensagem de erro em todas páginas de erro *500 Internal Error Server*, semelhante a isto:

[image: 500 internal server error]

Se a sua hospedagem/servidor permite instalar coisas por terminal (ssh) você pode tentar algo como (sendo Debian ou Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Note que será necessário reiniciar o servidor, todavia se não tem acesso ao SSH então você terá que entrar em contato com o suporte para habilitar.

Vejas as diferenças de configurações do mod_php:

- **php_flag** é usado quando há valores booleanos, que configurações do php.ini que aceitam apenas 1 ou 0, On ou Off e true ou false, por exemplo:

  ```
  php_flag display_startup_errors off
  php_flag display_errors off
  ```
- **php_value** é usado quando não se trata de ligar ou desligar (como On e Off), no caso usamos podemos usar para definir caminhos e limites em megas, por exemplo:

  ```
  php_value  upload_max_filesize  25M
  php_value error_log  /foo/bar/baz/erros.log
  ```
- **php_admin_flag** não pode ser usado no .htaccess, você só pode configurar ele no Apache e isto permite sobreescrever qual configuração do php.ini, diferente dos anteriores que tem limitações.

Também é interessante ressaltar que muitos servidores não deixam editar o `php.ini` e não tem `mod_php` mas eles tem a opção de editar um arquivo no usuário local que sobrescreve algumas *flags* ou valores do *php.ini* (consulte o suporte para ver se existe disponibilidade), um exemplo é o [PHPRC (PHP runtime configuration ou Configuração em tempo de execução do PHP)](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.php), você terá que verificar se existe esta disponibilidade.

O interessante do [PHPRC](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.php), é que muitas vezes é possível criar um arquivo de configuração pra cada versão do PHP (alguns servidores permitem usar versões diferentes do PHP para cada domínio), então digamos que você quer usar no PHP5.5 o [Opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) então basta criar um arquivo pra esta versão, mas você tem outro domínio que usar PHP5.4 e este não suporta o [Opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php), pois requer PECL, uma solução alternativa que poderia usar é o [Xcache](https://xcache.lighttpd.net), então você pode configurar o php5.4 com [Xcache](https://xcache.lighttpd.net) sem conflitar com o php5.5.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com esse [site](https://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess) tem como sim.

Basta adicionar isso no seu `.htacess`:

```
#configuração php
php_value  upload_max_filesize  10M
```

Também outra boa referência está aqui nessa pergunta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812154/overriding-php-ini-on-server)

Comment: Tem um detalhe. Esta configuração somente é alterada em runtime se o server permitir isso. Em hospedagens brasileiras por exemplo, é bem difícil que se consiga fazer isso. É uma configuração do PHP que a hospedagem impõe para evitar mal uso.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `ini_set()` no PHP! Basta colocar o conteúdo da linha do .ini como parâmetro:

```
<?php
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "10000");
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: A resposta é interessante, mas antes de colocar um exemplo se certifique que funciona. Eu corrigi. Outra nota, `ini_set` não vai funcionar em todos servidores e provavelmente tem série de limitações através do nivel de permissão de usuário.

Comment: Nem todas as propriedades do .ini funcionam no ini_set().. Para se certificar de qual é possível usar no ini_set(), você pode acessar o link a seguir e verificar qual são aceitas:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

A partir da coluna Changeable em conjunto com as informações desse link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php
Você poderá saber quais e onde podem ser usadas/cofiguradas as propriedades do .ini