# Erro ao enviar algumas fotos

Tags: php, mysql, html5, data

Fiz um script que faz upload de uma foto pro servidor e guarda o nome no MySQL, mas algumas fotos ele não envia, alguns tipos tipo JPEG de 3 mega pra cima não é enviado e dá erro.

index.php:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div>
        <label for="foto">Foto do Perfil</label>
        <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto">
        <button type="submit" >enviar</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
<php
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
include_once("../../assets/tools/config.php");
$nome_temporario = $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
$nome_real = $_FILES["foto"]["name"]; 
copy($nome_temporario,"../../assets/userPic/$nome_real");
$foto = $_FILES['foto']["name"];
$url = $base_url."assets/userPic/".$foto; 
//atualizar no BD
$sql = "UPDATE users SET  foto='$url' WHERE email='$email'";
$salvar = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//Verificar se salvou no banco de dados
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Perfil atualizado com sucesso! 
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span></button></div>";
    header("Location: ./");
} else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Erro ao atualizar seu perfil! :(
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span></button></div>";
    header("Location: ./");
}
```

Comment: Acrescente na pergunta as últimas mensagens do log de erro do PHP referentes à esse script.

Comment: já deu uma olhada nas configurações do php max_upload_site e max_post_size ?

Comment: Não tenho log de erro, na mensagem de erro apenas fala que deu errado. Boa idéia, vou dar uma olhada nesse max_upload.

Comment: Precisa ter log de erro e usar, é o mínimo do mínimo se pretende usar PHP pra qualquer coisa minimamente séria.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser algo de configuração, quando vai verificar que tipo de imagem pode subir deve tbm colocar o tamanho máximo permitido,tenho um trecho em codeigniter que seria:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './public/images/noiva';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = 2000;
$config['max_width'] = 1024;
$config['max_heigth'] = 768;
```

Teria que ver como ficaria no PHP raiz.

Comment: Valeus, nem tinha percebido!

Comment: vou fazer uns testes

Answer (score 2):

Bem provavelmente é uma configuração no seu `php.ini`

Procure no seu php.ini essas configurações:

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
```

E as altere para um número mais elevado, após alteração, tente novamente inserir uma imagem.

Comment: tem uma forma de usar htaccess pra isso?

Comment: Para utilizar configuração PHP no .htaccess, você vai precisar do mod_php instalado no servidor, senão ele te dará um "Internal Server Error". Tendo isso instalando, daí tu coloca no .htaccess: `php_value  upload_max_filesize  10M`. Referência: [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113873/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-configurara-o-upload-max-filesize-via-htaccess)